# Need to show my iphone application in sharing list of youtube video

Tags: ios, iphone, youtube

I want my application to be listed in sharing option of device.

I want to show my app in sharing list when user is Playing youtube video and press share option.

Facebook and twitter is already there in list,want to add my own app in that list.

I don't know exactly is it possible or not?

If possible then how can i implement this in my application.

I'm developing app for ios 7+ versions.

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 0):

For iOS8+, see the [App Extension Programming Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/General/Conceptual/ExtensibilityPG/index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014214). Check "share" extension.